# Increment of a Positive Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Let $a_i$, $i= 1,...,N$, be a collection of real numbers, $a_i \neq 0$,
 such that 
$\sum_i^N \frac{1}{a_i} > 0 $

The question asks to show whether the following is true:

a)
$$ \sum_i^N \frac{1}{a_i} >   \sum_i^N \frac{1}{a_i+\delta}$$ where $\delta \in (0, \min_i (|a_i|))$.

b) Assume you have another collection of real numbers $b_i$, $|b_i|<|a_i|$, and the series  $\sum_i^N \frac{b_i}{a_i} >0$, 
$$ \sum_i^N \frac{b_i}{a_i} >   \sum_i^N \frac{b_i}{a_i+\delta}$$ where $\delta \in (0, \min_i (|a_i|))$.

If not can you provide a counter example.

Update: Assume that $\delta < |a_i| ,\forall i$. (Sorry I had to do this update, because the original question is much complicated than the one above) 
Update 2: Added part (b) above.

Comment: So the $a_i$'s are not assumed positive, and we assume $a_i + \delta \ne 0$?

Comment: Yes, $a_i$ could be any real number other than 0, thanks for the comment I need to add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false. Take $a_1 = -1, a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = 2$ and $\delta = 2$.

However, it is true if $0 \not\in (a_i, a_i + \delta)$ for all $i$. This can be proved by differentiation (or otherwise).

**Edit.** To prove the last statement, note that the function $1/x$ is decreasing on any interval that does not include zero. Therefore $1/(a_i + \delta) < 1/a_i$.

Comment: Can you add more details of that case, when $0 \not \in (a_i,a_i+\delta$)? 
because the problem that I had in mind was something like that, in fact I have $\delta < |a_i| , \forall i$

Comment: What if we have $b_i $ be any real number, and the series becomes $\sum_i \frac{b_i}{a_i}$ , where  $|a_i| > |b_i|$ and the other conditions are as above would that still hold?

Comment: Not in general. If $b_i > 0$, then yes, with almost the same proof. (Consider the function $b_i/x$.)

Comment: what would be an example where this might fail, for any value of $b_i$?

Comment: $N= 1$. $-1/(-2 + x) $.

Comment: Ok last question, what if $a_i$ is restricted to be positive, i.e. same as part (b) but $a_i>0 \forall i $

Comment: $a_1 = 4$, $b_1 = -1$, $a_2 =100$, $b_2 = 50$, $\delta = 1$.