# Show monotonicity of an Alternating Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $a_i$, $i= 1,2,..,N$, be a collection of positive numbers, such that 
$\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{(-1)^i}{a_i} > 0 $

The question asks to show whether the following is true:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{(-1)^i}{a_i} >   \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{(-1)^i}{a_i+\delta}$$ where $\delta \in (0, \infty)$.

If not can you provide a counter example.

Note:This is modified problem of another post:
[Increment of a Positive Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1630160/increment-of-a-positive-series/1630166#1630166)

Side note: If you can solve it for any of the terms has sign different than the rest, that would be great as well.

Comment: Now, why would you expect it to be true, and what have you tried?

Comment: I am interested in this kind of series, I tested it using Matlab over thousandths of instances. It goes without saying that the order of the terms does not matter. What complicates things is that we do not have sum of monotone functions anymore.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that you didn't find counter-examples, since intuition tells me there should be one. Can you clarify that it is $\sum_{i=1}^N$?

Comment: updated, I found non!, I do not think it is counter intuitive, in fact it is intuitive, if you think about the fact that it is positive, meaning the positive terms are greater than the negative ones, thus when they decrease they do that slower, but the sum complicates things a bit.

Comment: Is there a counter-example if you remove the condition on $δ$ and only require $δ > 0$?

Comment: No, probably I have to update the question.

Comment: Yea my intuition said that if it holds it should hold for all $δ > 0$. I don't see any obvious reason yet, but it's not that counter-intuitive as I first thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assertion is false. Counterexample:
$$(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{10} ) = (2,5,10,5,10,5,10,5,10,5)\quad\text{ and }\quad \delta = 1$$
We have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{10} \frac{(-1)^k}{a_k} = \frac{1}{10} < \frac{3}{22} = \sum_{k=1}^{10}
\frac{(-1)^k}{a_k + \delta}$$

Comment: Thanks, I am wondering how did you come up with the example? is it by inspection or you solved for $\delta$ or other technique.

Comment: @MrD My intuition tell me if it fail, it will be caused by some sort of non-linearity. So I start with a term that is very small compare to the rest to make the effect of non-linearity more prominent. I want $\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{(-1)^k}{a_k}$ remains to be positive. Since I make some term small, I think I need to make some other term large to compensate for that. I throw a few example to an CAS and find a counterexample pretty quickly.